# What are these icons by my commit

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I recently began working on project and I committed and pushed it using Github for Windows.

But if you look at the `.gitignore` , there is a `:camel:` and a `:boom:` icon next to the commit. Are these of any purpose? They seemed to have been auto generated by Github for Windows. How can I add these icons to my own commits, and what other icons are there?

**EDIT**

Messing around github, I discovered that these are emoji's (http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/), and that they are supported in Github's markdown syntax. Still, I wonder why  Github for Windows put *these* in the `.gitignore` commit.

Comment: what was the solution to remove? txs

Comment: @SQLDBA Just edit the commit message, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could have been the result of some overzealous [emoji autocompletion](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/06/09/ghfw-2/), which is now a feature with GitHub for Windows (when you type '`:`'):

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/19977/3218916/0293bf30-eff0-11e3-816b-68af901cf5a4.png]

(as shown in the article "[GitHub for Windows 2.0](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/06/09/ghfw-2/)", which actually takes advantage of those emoji in commit message)