# What does this icon space:invader mean in Github?

Tags: github

[image: what does it mean]

When I hover on it, it says :space_invader: . What does it mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about emoji on a website.

Comment: I don't find anywhere reference to the meaning of github icons since we all use github, it make sense to know what it mean.

Comment: No need to post such questions here. Instead, use emoji cheatsheet page for it.

Comment: Possibly, the OP was wondering how that icon got into his commit. I did, and landed here googling for the answer. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27572208/1016065)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon you are referring to is an emoticon. Emoticons can be used in commit names on Github, which is what has been done above. A list of emoticons that can be used on Github is available [here](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/). So the commit text would be `:space_invader: Initial setup for UI_bootstrap and angularjs`